# Toggle Comments shortcut key

Tags: salesforce-id

I am looking for the shortcut to be able to toggle comments in `Force.com IDE`. I use it often in the regular flavour of eclipse and other IDEs. Looking at the preferences page, it seems like I should be able to use <kbd>mac-key</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, but that does not work. It works if I open the file with a Java editor.

Maybe this is a mac problem, because I have not been able to find others complaining.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why so few people complain about that feature not working is because there are more important features that don't work.

Here's a common set of complaints:

- Auto-completion is hit and miss, can freeze the IDE.
- Auto-indenting is awful, usually making a mess.
- Can't organize members.
- Can't block un-indent.
- Fewer useful warnings, like a missing "unused variables" warning.
- Auto-closure features don't work well.
- Auto-completion with methods makes the parameters plain text instead of code markers (can't tab to each parameter).
- Refactoring is generally useless.
- Random errors stop all future auto-builds without deleting the entire workspace and/or project.
- Synchronization is hit and miss.
- CVS is somewhat painful.
- Deployments are slow.
- Test Runner makes it hard to figure out why/where tests failed, relative to Developer Console.
- Retrievals are slow.

I could continue, but I think you see what we're working with. There are numerous issues that we deal with every day. The lack of a block commenting hot key is pretty low on the list.

As a workaround, I usually use Perl, Ant, and Programmer's Notepad as a combination working-ish IDE. Using Ant, deploys and retrieves are faster, and I can use Perl scripts to detect modifications and build custom packages for modified components only. Programmer's Notepad has a language extension feature, but I haven't bothered, since I just use Java highlighting for Apex Code and triggers, and XML mode for pages and controllers. I miss out on auto-completion, but at least the system doesn't waste time giving me useless auto-completions, either.

Hopefully the next revision (due any day now, from my understanding) will provide better capabilities than prior versions.

Comment: So the short answer is "It does not work"... great answer. Thanks a lot. I love this site. It is painful to see Eclipse associated with this mess... I noticed you said `Can't block un-indent.` - if you mean reduce the indentation by one tab level across multiple lines, then it works for me most of the time. I use `shift` + `tab` (a small consolation)

Comment: Love how you said "most" of the time. Works like a champ until I need it to, then I find myself using Programmer's Notepad to clean up my source. Well, it's supposed to get better in the next release. Here's hoping.